# Prevent https on Openshift

Tags: openshift

I want to cancel https on Openshift, I've just known that the server returns a header Strict-Transport-Security which forces https, is there anyway that I can force http when using Openshift because i'm getting some issues with chrome, it is not loading some resources from http sources when using https

Answer (score 1):

The bug has been documented here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=908417 (login required)

This should be fixed in the next update to OpenShift, and when using Google Chrome version 26 or later.

Comment: This bug has been fixed, the server no longer forces https