# Openshift https bug occurs on all browsers not on chrome only

Tags: https, openshift

According to this post [Prevent https on Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372953/prevent-https-on-openshift)
https forcing happens only on Chrome but that is not true this happens in all browsers.

So it's not a google chrome bug it's an openshift bug. Does Openshift intend to fix this ? I can't see no other post mentioning it.

Update :  I just use Wordpress here http://reboltutorial.net so nothing special (I uploaded a wordpress I have migrated from a former hosting so I didn't use Wordpress from Openshfit still it should work without https like it did on my former host)

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample ruby-1.9 app here: http://naruto-konoha.rhcloud.com . It doesn't force HTTPS for me on both Firefox and Chrome. Could you visit this and check if it forces HTTPS for you?

Alternatively, is the issue you're experiencing only the case with a particular app? If yes, could you check if it's something in your code that forces HTTPS?

Hope that helps.

Comment: True It doesn't force https with your site. I just use Wordpress so nothing special.