# Don't force SSL on OpenShift gear?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openshift

I have a simple PHP gear set up on OpenShift. I had everything working well until I added a custom alias for my own domain. I am on the free option and don't have the ability to configure an SSL certificate, and I don't want to, this site is very simple.

The problem that I get is that its forcing my alis to `https` even though I have not set that up. I also haven't configured any apache rewrites to force ssl.

For my DNS settings I am just pointing the www cname to my gear as they explained, I have not done anything in the DNS so force ssl.

According to this there was a similar bug:
[Prevent https on Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372953/prevent-https-on-openshift)

It says that particular problem was resolved (that was a year ago) but I am still getting this.

Here is my URL so you can see what it is doing:
[www.libertypuppies.us](http://www.libertypuppies.us)

When you go there it will force you to `https` and warn you that the certificate is not trusted.

This is on a php gear. I have no other gears, just the one.

How do I configure it to not force SSL and just stay on `http`?

EDIT (more info):

I tried the following in .htaccess but it didn't work. Either I wrote the rewrite wrong or the problem is higher up:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS:X-Forwarded-Proto} !http  
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

And this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

None of which worked. If you notice when you go to the site it also adds `/app` to the path.

Comment: I just had this happen again on a different openshift gear. Once again the solution was to delete the alias and make a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been something internal with OpenShift. I deleted the alias and made it again. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) in your  .htaccess to make redirect all traffic to http.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with more information.