# How to import the *.rhcloud.com into Chrome(ium)?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, openshift

I would like to import the [*.rhcloud.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A5YI.png) certificate into my Chromium installation in order to prevent Chromium from informing me about the insecure connection each time I am accessing my Openshift installation through `https`.

I exported the certificate using Firefox. Then I tried to import the certificate in Chromium. It prompts me to enter the password that was used to encrypt this certificate file. The password is unknown to me.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: The certificate was issued by DigiCert and should be already accepted by Chrome. The problem is probably more a mismatch of name with the certificate, i.e. that the hostname you access is not contained in the certificate.  Importing the certificate will not help in this case. Can you provide the URL you are having the problems with?

Comment: Hello Steffen, indeed it results from a mismatch of the hostname because I'm using a custom domain through a CNAME entry. Nevertheless, is there a way to let Chromium permanently accept this connection as secure?

Comment: You should be able to just accept the non-matching certificate using the advanced options in the warning. There will be several clicks involved because they explicitly made it hard to accept a bad certificate by just clicking around. That is you need to read and understand the warnings and dialogs and only then you will be able to accept the invalid certificate.  Simply importing as trusted will not work because the name does not match the certificate.

Comment: This is not a permanent solution. I have to trust the unsecure connection each time that I access the url via `https` (see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/PnSLHLZ.png)).  in other words, Chrome does not remember that I accepted this connection as trusted.

Comment: Yes, it looks like Chrome will not longer allow to permanently accept this kind of verification error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments Chrome isn't going to allow you to permanently store this exception. Just use [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans) to add free SSL or [force non-secure pages using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157382/dont-force-ssl-on-openshift-gear).